# Move bone to a certain location python

Tags: python, scripting, rigging, armature, bones

I have a bone and two empties, how in edit mode I can move the head of the bone to the location of empty1 and the tip to the location of empty2 using python?

I'm trying the below script but it doesn't work as I want it to move to the empty location as highlighted below.

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
obj = bpy.data.objects['metarig']
obj.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
emp = bpy.data.objects['Empty']
for bone in obj.data.edit_bones:
    if bone.name == 'hips':
        bone.head = emp.location
```

My .blend file can be found here: [image]

[image]

Comment: edit bones are in "local" coordinates, eg a head of (0, 0, 0) is at the location of the armature object origin etc.  To convert multiply by the armature object's world matrix inverse.  Does your armature have scale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the local coordinates by applying the inverse matrix of the armature to the global coordinates.

```
# obj       the armature (scaled)
# emp       the empty in world space (no parent)

bone.head =  obj.matrix_world.inverted() * emp.location
```

Comment: `emp.matrix_world.to_translation()` is global location of empty with / without parent, constraint etc etc.